# Why won't my USB device show in device manager?

Tags: windows, usb, device-manager

I have an issue where my USB oscilloscope is no longer showing up in device manager.

The system plays the hardware inserted sound.

I have located the device in the registry and tried removing all records but that did not resolve the issue so I undid the changes.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suggestion to uninstall all the hardware listed in the USB section of device manager like the hubs and controllers. Once I did that, I clicked search for new hardware and the computer proceeded to re-install all the devices and related USB (and Bluetooth) peripherals that had been recorded even if they were not plugged in.

Low and behold my oscilloscope now showed up in other devices (the driver has to be installed manually by the way).

Once the driver was installed, the program could now see the device.